# implementing loading bar in python C extension (Python C API)

Tags: python, c++, progress-bar, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I would like to display the current state of my C++ python extension (.pyd module) in the python interpreter window as a loading bar, like `pip` or `conda` does when it is telling you the current download progress. In other words, I would like to write a message to the python window, and then remove it and replace it with a new message.

Is there a way to output a message from the c++ .pyd module into the python window, and then clear the previous line to replace it with a new message, so as to implement a loading bar?